# How to print out timestamps in given range in Python?

Tags: python, date, for-loop, timestamp

new programmer just getting started with Python.

How would I be able to print out a list of timestamps, every second, given a date range, for example 4/12/17 through 4/21/17 in date -d format?

The output would be something along the lines of

Wed Apr 12 00:00:00 CST 2017
Wed Apr 12 00:00:01 CST 2017
.
.
.
Fri Apr 21 00:00:00 CST 2017

It would ideally be in a nice, vertical list for the output.

I am guessing the solution involves nested for loops, but I just can't wrap my head around the process of making it happen.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `datetime`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

At a high level, I would start with initializing a `datetime` object with the first timestamp in your range, and a 1-second `timedelta` object.

```
import datetime
myDatetime = datetime.datetime(# TODO)
myTimedelta = datetime.timedelta(# TODO)
```

Then you could use a while loop and an `endDatetime` object with your last time in the range:

```
endDateTime = datetime.datetime(# TODO)
while myDatetime <= endDatetime:
    print(myDatetime) # need to format it to look like your example
    myDatetime = myDatetime + myTimedelta
```

Or you can calculate how many seconds are between the first and last end time and use a `for` loop:

```
seconds = # TODO
for i in range(seconds+1):
    print(myDatetime + (i * myTimedelta))
```